# JFugue Android 40BPM until 57BPM error

Tags: android, jfugue

When I set T40 it supposed to play in tempo 40 bpm but it plays in tempo 135 bpm!!!
When I set T41 it is in tempo 145 bpm and this continue until T57.
From T58 it is ok I mean is in tempo 58 bpm.

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("T40 V0 I[Piano] Cq Cq Cq Cq");
Player player = new Player();
player.play(pattern);
```

The same error occur again when I set T[Grave] .It supposed to be in tempo 40 bpm but it is again in tempo 135 bpm!!!

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("T[Grave] V0 I[Piano] Cq Cq Cq Cq");
Player player = new Player();
player.play(pattern);
```

Comment: Which version of JFugue are you using? I tested with JFugue 5.0.5, and this is not an issue. If you're using "JFugue for Android", unfortunately that is not an official JFugue project that I have any involvement in. (I'm the author of JFugue)

Comment: Thank you. I use JFugue for Android 4.0.3 from here https://github.com/kshoji/JFugue-for-Android. Can you fix it please or can you release JFugue 5 for android also? I am using Android Studio.

Comment: I am not involved in the JFugue-for-Android project. I would encourage you to contact kshoji (looking at the site, it looks like the latest uses JFugue 5.01?). I hope Android M, with MIDI support, will make a JFugue 5 port to Android easier.

Comment: @DavidKoelle Hello David, Does JFugue work on Android? Also if not what is the Class/or Library responsible for playback in JFugue? Is it possible to somhow return the midi track from JFugue and pass to a sequencer in Android? Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: JFugue does not work with Android. JFugue requires javax.sound.midi, which is not part of Android's version of Java. I have not yet experimented with the newer android.media.midi package. While JFugue won't work out of the box, it would seem to me (looking at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/package-summary) that Android support for JFugue is feasible.